# How can I mount an AFS filesystem?

Tags: 10.10, mount, afs

My current method is to mount the filesystem via SSH using Nautilus's graphical interface, but I would much prefer to be able to use some tool that mounts the AFS filesystem and gives me access to AFS-specific features (permissions, etc.). I've tried installing OpenAFS via apt-get, but so far the kernel module has refused to compile. Also, assuming I get OpenAFS installed, I'm not quite sure how to actually mount the remote filesystem to, say, `/media/afs` or some directory.

I'm running Maverick with the 2.6.36-020636-generic kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried installing using the Ubuntu-Kernel? It seems likely the module not compiling has to do with using the mainline Kernel.

Comment: I was thinking that. I feel bad asking this, but what's the easiest way to revert?

Comment: It should still be installed. When grub does it's thing on boot (for a few tenths of a second), press ESC to see the grub menu. Then select the older kernel version you want to boot. You can also just remove the mainline kernel for now.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I'll have to mess with it at some later date. I've been using the newer kernel because it lets me use vga_switcheroo, which is important because the driver for my discrete card doesn't work and sucks a lot of power, and the potential benefits of OpenAFS don't balance the power savings (and I currently lack time to play with both options extensively). Thanks, though!

Comment: For GRUB 2 you have to use **Shift** instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: In the end, it appeared that the problem was due to using the mainline kernel. Once the Ubuntu kernel was updated to include vga_switcheroo, I tried again and installing OpenAFS via apt-get worked just fine. Running `sudo service openafs-client start` starts OpenAFS and mounts the AFS directory at /afs, and I use `klog username` to authenticate via Kerberos.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, assuming I get OpenAFS installed, I'm not quite sure how to actually mount the remote filesystem to, say, /media/afs or some directory.

To specifically answer this part, this can be done by passing the -mountdir option to afsd, or modifying the /etc/openafs/cacheinfo file. To mount AFS on /media/afs instead of just /afs, pass `-mountdir /media/afs` to afsd, or specify the /media/afs directory in the first field inside /etc/openafs/cacheinfo. See [afsd(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/afsd.8.html) and [cacheinfo(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/cacheinfo.5.html). AFS is traditionally always mounted on /afs, though; there's usually no reason to change it.

In order to pass the -mountdir option to afsd in Ubuntu, you need to modify /etc/openafs/afs.conf before the openafs client starts, and add the extra options to the OPTIONS or VERBOSE variables. It's probably easier to just modify cacheinfo instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check this article: http://lug.rose-hulman.edu/wiki/HOWTO_Use_sshfs_to_mount_AFS/DFS_home

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks! That's more or less what I was doing, except via Nautilus' built-in system. I didn't realise sshfs existed, though, which is good to know.

Comment: Actually, they also have an article about doing AFS with OpenAFS, which was perfect! Thanks!